# How to target nth of class when other selectors/classes exists

Tags: jquery, css

I'm finding it hard to target the nth of a class when another class or selector exists in the same grouping.

So for example, I'm trying to get every 5th selector of a specific class called "item". But there's other selectors in the grouping called "title", which throw off the nth count.

```
<ul>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="title">Title</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
    ...
</ul>

.item {
    background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(5n+5) {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

I put up a fiddle here of the full example code: https://jsfiddle.net/pb12gjp1/1/

In the fiddle, the result shows the 4th instance of ".item" having cyan applied verus the 5th one having it applied. The ".title" li's throw off the count as they're included in the nth count.

Is there any way to tackle it with jQuery? I've found there's not many options to handle it with CSS only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can use a selector directly over the `li`</strike>

```
ul li:nth-child(5n+5) {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pb12gjp1/2/)

Sorry I understood your problem wrongly, Use `.filter()` with a relevant logic to solve your problem.

```
var items = $(".item");
items.filter(function(i){
  return i % 5 == 4;
}).css("background-color","cyan");
//or you can add a class here.
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pb12gjp1/5/)

---

As per your new requirement you have to use `.each()` along with `.nextUntil()` and `.filter()` to achieve what you want.

```
var titles = $(".title");
titles.each(function(i){
  $(this).nextUntil(".title").filter(function(i){
   return i % 5 == 4;
  }).css("background-color","cyan");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pb12gjp1/7/)

Comment: The result there is the same as mine. The 4th ".item" has the cyan background applied vs the 5th one having it applied.

Comment: Filtering I think is a good idea. But the last ".title" class in there throws off that final count. You can see, it takes into affect the ".item" right before it. Changed the title here to make it stand out more: https://jsfiddle.net/pb12gjp1/6/

Comment: @RyanPalmer So you want to select the each 5th `.item` after `.title`? Right?

Comment: Right. But the ordering and amount of titles and items in the lists varies from page to page. It's all dumped into the pages based on user input, so it's never the same exact order or amount.

Comment: @RyanPalmer I hope, the new edit will suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your markup is semantically incorrect.

Instead, I would use nested lists with `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type`

```css
ul > li > ul > :nth-child(5n+5) {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Title
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Title
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Title
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```